# Imprimir uma linha de um array bidimensional em Perl

Tags: array, join, perl

Tenho um array `@data`, bidimensional, e quero gravar linha após linha num arquivo. Estou fazendo assim, para cada linha `$i`:

```perl
print (ECR $data[$i][0]);
for $j (1 .. $lastcol) {
  print (ECR "," . $data[$i][$j]);
}
print (ECR "\n");
```

Mas gostaria de fazer algo do tipo:

```perl
print (ECR join (",", $data[$i][0 .. lastcol])) . "\n";
```

Como fazer?

Comment: por que você quer fazer assim ? já tentou ?
mesmo que funcione, acho que não vai valer a pena, vai duplicar o conteúdo da matriz bidimensional em memória...teria que haver um motivo específico para fazer deste jeito que você quer

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução de apenas uma linha de código utilizando a função [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
print ECR map { (join (",", @{$_}))."\n" } @data;
```

Outra solução, mais simples, com poucas linhas de código utilizando [referências](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html):

```
for my $linha (@data) {
    print ECR join (",", @{$linha}), "\n";
}
```

Uma solução mais similar a que você propôs, usando um indexador e referências:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @data; $i++) {
    print (ECR join (",", @{$data[$i]}) . "\n");
}
```

Por fim, se realmente for necessário fazer o slice das colunas:

```
my $num_linha = @data;
my $num_coluna = @{$data[0]};

for (my $i = 0; $i < $num_linha; $i++) {
        print ECR join (",", $data[$i]->@[0..$num_coluna-1])."\n";
}
```

Caso queira fazer coisas mais avançadas e rápidas no formato CSV, utilize o [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) ou [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS).